# My CSS stopped working

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a problem with my css file which I haven't been able to solve for a while. I'm relatively new in java web technologies and I have no clue what could've caused that. I'm trying to write a MVC based application where my servlets work as controllers, jsp's as views and my database is my model. My HomeController for now supposed to retrieve names of categories from database and forward it to the view (home.jsp). It works fine, I can display categories in my view but since I've implemented HomeController my css file have stopped working. So I ended up with working controller and awfull view. I have no idea where the problem is.

Here's significant files:

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

  <context-param>
    <param-name>databaseURL</param-name>
    <param-value>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/buyandsell</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>username</param-name>
    <param-value>admin</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>password</param-name>
    <param-value>admin</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>HomeController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>controllers.HomeController</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>HomeController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

HomeController:

```
public class HomeController extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String databaseURL;
    private String username;
    private String password;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public HomeController() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
       // Retrieve the database-URL, username, password from webapp init parameters
       super.init(config);
       ServletContext context = config.getServletContext();
       databaseURL = context.getInitParameter("databaseURL");
       username = context.getInitParameter("username");
       password = context.getInitParameter("password");
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        RequestDispatcher rd = null;
        ArrayList<Category> categories = null;
        try {
            // Indicating proper database driver
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");   
            // Creating a database connection object
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(databaseURL, username, password);
            // Creating a statement object inside our connection object
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            // Fetching a categories names
            categories = fetchCategories(stmt);
            // Setting categories for the view to display
            request.setAttribute("categories", categories);
            rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/home.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if(stmt != null) stmt.close();
                if(conn != null) conn.close();
            } catch(SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Method responsible for fetching categories names from database.
     * @param Reference to statement object.
     * @return Returns object which contains names of available categories in array list or null if SQLException was thrown.
     */

    private ArrayList<Category> fetchCategories(Statement stmt) {
        ArrayList<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM categories";
        try {
            // Retrieving data from defined query
            ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            // Creating category objects which will be forwarded to the view
            while(rset.next()) {
                int id = rset.getInt(1);
                String name = rset.getString(2);
                int parentId = rset.getInt(3);
                categories.add(new Category(id, name, parentId));
            }
            return categories;
        } catch(SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        return null;
    }

}
```

and fragments of home.jsp:

```
                   <%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
                   <%@ page import="models.Category" %>
                   <ul>
                       <%
                            ArrayList<Category> categories = (ArrayList<Category>) request.getAttribute("categories");
                            if(categories != null && !categories.isEmpty()) {
                                for(int i=0; i<categories.size(); i++) {
                       %>
                                    <li><a href="category?id=<%= categories.get(i).getId() %>"><span><%= categories.get(i).getName() %></span></a>
                       <%
                                }
                            }
                       %>
                   </ul>
               </div>
```

and:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" type="text/css" />        
    <title>Buy&amp;Sell - online auctions.</title>
</head>
```

stylesheet.css is placed in WebContent folder.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** CSS file have been in the same folder since the beginning.

Comment: Have you verified that if you _remove_ your HomeController the CSS starts working again?

Comment: I have now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've mapped your servlet to `/`. That is a mapping which means: every request goes to the servlet. So, when the browser sends a request to /stylesheet.css, the request goes to the servlet instead of going being handled by the default container-provided servlet which would serve the static file.

Map your servlet to another URL.

Comment: Wasn't expecting that ;-) Thank you very much.